# Coloring plot in Mathematica according to labels

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, plot

I have a dataset with labels which I would like to plot with points colored according to their label. Is there a simple way how to get current line numer inside plot, so that I can determine which category does the point belong to?

I understood that `x,y,z` are the coordinates of plotted data, but it doesn't help for the external labels.

This is quite ugly and it works just on sorted dataset with regular distribution.

```
    data = Import["http://ftp.ics.uci.edu/pub/machine-learning-databases/iris/iris.data"];
    data = Drop[data, -1]; (*there one extra line at the end*)
    inData = data[[All, 1 ;; 4]];
    labels = data[[All, 5]];
    ListPlot3D[inData,
      ColorFunction -> 
        Function[{x, y, z}, 
          If[y < 0.33, RGBColor[1, 1, 0.], 
               If[y < 0.66, RGBColor[1, 0, 0.], RGBColor[1, 0, 1]]
          ]
        ]
    ]
```

Expected result:

[image: expected result of visualization]

Comment: Where are the labels in your dataset? Please describe the structure

Comment: labels are strings, it could be replaced by numbers or RGB colors, it doesn't really matter

Comment: The question is still not entirely clear, a sample dataset would be good. Do you need to plot separate points, or a surface? What format is the data in?  Suggestion: Can you separate your points according to category, and plot each category on its own?  `GatherBy` could be useful.

Comment: I've edited the question, hopefully it's more clear. I prefere a surface in this case because it seems to be more understandable. There are 4 parameters which makes it harder. Choosing just 3 of them is another option for a visualization

Comment: List...3D[{ }] will take triples as input. You have four dimensional vectors in `inData`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose that `points` is the lists of coordinates and `labels` a list of the corresponding labels so for example

```
points = Flatten[Table[{i, j, Sin[i j]}, 
   {i, 0, Pi, Pi/20}, {j, 0, Pi, Pi/10}], 1];
labels = RandomChoice[{"label a", "label b", "label c"}, Length[points]];
```

Each label corresponds to a colour which I'm writing as a list of rules, e.g.

```
rules = {"label a" -> RGBColor[1, 1, 0], 
   "label b" -> RGBColor[1, 0, 0], "label c" -> RGBColor[1, 0, 1]};
```

Then the points can be plotted in the colour corresponding to their label as follows

```
ListPointPlot3D[Pick[points, labels, #] & /@ Union[labels], 
   PlotStyle -> Union[labels] /. rules]
```

[image: plot]

**Edit**

To colour individual points in a `ListPlot3D` you can use `VertexColors`, for example

```
ListPlot3D[points, VertexColors -> labels /. rules, Mesh -> False]
```

[image: colouring points in a ListPlot3D]

Comment: This is great for single points, what I imagined was something for demostration of multidimensional data, like the right image http://i44.tinypic.com/33bivzb.png When using `Pick` the layers cover each other. Anyway thanks for a quick answer!

Comment: @Tombart I've extended my answer.

Comment: Very nice, thanks a lot! There's just small problem, that the supplied list of has dimensions {150,1} and I would need dimensions {150,4}. I'm quite new to Mathematica, so the syntax is still a mystery for me. I rewrote it to `ListPlot3D[points, 
 VertexColors -> {Map[({#, #, #, #}) &, labels] /. rules}, 
 Mesh -> False]` and it works like a charm :)

Answer (score 3):

For Example:

```
(* Build the labeled structure and take a random permutation*)
f[x_, y_] = Sqrt[100 - x x - y y];
l = RandomSample@Flatten[{Table[{{"Lower", {x, y, f[x, y] - 5}},
                                 {"Upper", {x, y, 5 - f[x, y]}}},
                          {x, -5, 5, .1}, {y, -5, 5, .1}]}, 3];
(*Plot*)

Graphics3D[
 Riffle[l[[All, 1]] /. {"Lower" -> Red, "Upper" -> Green}, 
  Point /@ l[[All, 2]]], Axes -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: This is great for 3 dimensional data, I will need some more. I should have written it in the question, anyway thanks for an answer, I didn't know Riffle function before.